# puppeteer fileChooser not working nothing happening

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Hello I am trying to upload a file to a website using puppeteer and it seems that it is not working. When I do it manually I get notified to name the file like in this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIN81.png)

but when I do it using puppeteer using this code :

```
let visa_file = 'C:\Users\birbara2\Desktop\DubaiReal\residence.png';
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
page.waitForFileChooser(),
page.click('#file-drop-zone'), // some button that triggers file selection
]);
await fileChooser.accept([visa_file]);
```

I don't get an error but it doesn't seem to do anything when I capture a screenshot like this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkDTM.png) please help

this is the html of the element in question

```
<div tabindex="0"><input accept="image/png,image/jpeg,application/pdf" multiple="" type="file" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"><p>Edict Document</p></div>
```

Comment: What site? It's hard to help without being able to run it myself.

Comment: the problem is that the site requires login to get to that point and I am not allowed to share my client's info, otherwise I would gladly post the site. I can copy the source code if that helps or whatever other than the login info

Comment: I understand. Some sort of replication of the file picker component behavior would be sufficient, but that can be hard to do.

Comment: Do you know if the popup window should appear in a screenshot or does it only take the browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it is with how I wrote the path file. I copied the path from file explorer so it had '' as the separator instead of '/'

wrong : C:\Users\Desktop\pic.jpg

right : C:/Users/Desktop/pic.jpg